# Filter where a match exists in Array

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

When I modified my filter to only select an `ArtistDocument` whose `artist_ID` contains a match in the `artistIds` array, I get the following error.

> "The expression tree is not supported: {document}{artist_ID}" System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}

```
// array.
string[] artistsIds = new string[] { "123ABC", "456XYZ" };

// filter.
var filter = Builders<ArtistsDocument>.Filter.Where(p => p.artist_ID.Any(b => artistsIds.Contains(b.ToString())));
filter = filter & Builders<ArtistsDocument>.Filter.Eq("genre", "Rock");
filter = filter & Builders<ArtistsDocument>.Filter.Lt(x => x.transactionDate, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(Math.Abs(30) * (-1)));

// update.
var update = Builders<ArtistsDocument>.Update.Set("status", "Processing");

// options.
var options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<ArtistsDocument>
{
    Sort = Builders<ArtistsDocument>.Sort.Ascending(x => x.fileName).Ascending(x => x.priority),
    ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After
};

// document.
var doc = await artistsCollection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve what you want with ElemMatch

```
Builders<ArtistsDocument>.Filter.ElemMatch
```

something like this:

```
var elemMatchFilter = Builders<YourModel>
    .Filter
    .ElemMatch(x => x.YourArray, x => x.ArrayField1 == field1 && x.x.ArrayField2 == field2);
```

Comment: Is there an inverse for this? For example "none of the elements match"